# Uncaught SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I am getting this error with react-iframe. How should i resolve it?

Version:
react@16.13.1
react-iframe@1.8.0
(Please let me know if I have to add any more details)

```
  import Iframe from 'react-iframe
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  class TableList extends Component {
  render{
  return(
  <div>
    <Iframe url="some url"
    width="100%"
    height="1000"
    id="myId"
    // className="embed-responsive-item"
    display="initial"
    position="relative"
    X-Frame-Options="deny"
    />

  </div>
)
}
}
export default TableList;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if it was a copy/paste mistake but all imports must be defined between two quotes:

```
  import Iframe from 'react-iframe'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import Iframe from 'react-iframe';
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  class TableList extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Iframe url="some URL"
          width="100%"
          height="1000"
          id="myId"
          // className="embed-responsive-item"
          display="initial"
          position="relative"
          X-Frame-Options="deny"
        />
     </div>
   )
  }
}
export default TableList;
```

Try this.
You forget single quote in iframe import and brackets at render method.
render is a method so, it should have ()brackets my friend.

Hope It will help you.
Happy Coding!

Comment: I'm sorry that was a copy paste mistake i still get thet error.

Comment: Okay, can you share some more information like the whole error message screenshot and code as it is in your code editor? so, the people in this community can help you more precisely